# Is in django way save some data from database in RAM and after fixed time update it

Tags: python, django

I have some data that are fixed for all users. Now for each request I get the same data from DB.
Is there way to optimize it?

I tried to make a class which stores my needed data and init time by `datetime`; and it has a method which gets current time, compare it with init time, and if difference more than 12 hours it makes a new request to database, update value in class and returns it; else it returns the old value.
It works but i think that it isn't right way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yo can use Django's [cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/) to cache data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a caching library. In Python, you can use libraries like Redis, Memcached, or even Python's built-in functools.lru_cache for function-level caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cache response decorator:

```
def cache_response(func):
    """ Cache Response in seconds"""
    response = None
    last_updated = None

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal last_updated
        nonlocal response
        if not last_updated:
            last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return response
        if not response:
            last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
        dif = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=36000)  # 10 hours
        if dif > last_updated:
            last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return response
        return response

    return wrapper
```

and use it in your `views.py`

```
class FooAPIVIew(APIView):
    @cache_response
    def get(self, request):
        slow_query_result = foo()
        return Response(slow_query_result)
```

After first call all responses will be returned instantly for 10 hours
.